# Center Text on Rectangle in SVG

Tags: svg

I am trying to center some text ("Go") onto a blue rectangle in an SVG image, however the text is only appearing at the top left corner.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect fill="#8080ff" height="400" width="400" y="0" x="0"/>
    <text font-weight="bold" stroke="black" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Go</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `x="50%" y="50%"` then it will work.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect fill="#8080ff" height="400" width="400" y="0" x="0"/>
    <text font-weight="bold" stroke="black" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Go</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```